# How to create a Controller in CakePHP without setting up database tables?

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to cakePHP but I am a bit knowledgeable with Ruby on Rails. I tried creating a controller using the `cake bake` command in the console but it said:

> Your database does not have any tables

As far as I can remember in rails, it allowed me to create controllers without tables or even without setting up database. What I am trying to do is that I want to create a controller and a view for pages such as **Home**, **About**, and **Help**. I don't think those pages still need a model or a database table. Pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure you can create controllers and views... even models without tables.

But you can't bake them =D bake is just to read the database and help you create your classes from there. So if you dont have any table, you dont have anything to bake..

For the static pages such as Home, About and Help you could use the [PagesController](http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller)

Cheers!

Comment: you mean the pages_controller.php?

Comment: yes =) its on the link.. you'll need to copy the pages_controller.php in your app/controllers folder

Comment: Your link to the PagesController is broken.