# CakePHP scaffolding for RESTful Service Datasource

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to do scaffolding for a model which uses a RESTful datasource? I am using the [REST-Datasource-Plugin](https://github.com/nojimage/CakePHP-ReST-DataSource-Plugin) and would like to quickly generate the necessary actions and views.

Regards,

Roland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a mock database based on the schema of the REST resources. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094779/199072) to understand why baking would not function without the database.

I also did not do scaffolding, but rather generated the code with bake.